# frequency trail in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking into outliers detection. Brendan Gregg has a really nice [article](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2013/07/01/detecting-outliers/) and I'm especially intrigued by his visualizations. One of the methods he uses are [frequency trails](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2013/06/19/frequency-trails/).

[image: frequency trails]

I'm trying to reproduce this in matplotlib using [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/polys3d_demo.html) example. Which looks like this:

[image: polys3d_demo]

And the plot is based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4152016/948369

Now my issue is, like described by Brendan, that I have a continuous line that masks the outlier (I simplified the input values so you can still see them):

[image: masked outlier]

Any help on making the line "non-continuous" for non existent values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would stick with a flat 2D plot and displace each level by a set vertical amount. You'll have to play the the levels (in the code below I called it `displace`) to properly see the outliers, but this does a pretty good job at replicating your target image. The key, I think, is to set the "zero" values to `None` so pylab does not draw them.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import itertools

k = 20
X = np.linspace(0, 20, 500)
Y = np.zeros((k,X.size))

# Add some fake data
MU = np.random.random(k)
for n in xrange(k):
    Y[n] += np.exp(-(X-MU[n]*n)**2 / (1+n/3))
Y *= 50

# Add some outliers for show
Y += 2*np.random.random(Y.shape)

displace = Y.max()/4

# Add a cutoff
Y[Y<1.0] = None

face_colors = itertools.cycle(["#D3D820", "#C9CC54", 
                               "#D7DA66", "#FDFE42"])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='black')
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

for n,y in enumerate(Y):
    # Vertically displace each plot
    y0 = np.ones(y.shape) * n * displace
    y1 = y + n*displace

    plt.fill_between(X, y0,y1,lw=1, 
                     facecolor=face_colors.next(),
                     zorder=len(Y)-n)  
plt.show()
```

Comment: That looks pretty neat, I'll give it a shot later and give you feedback how it went.

Answer (score 6):

Seaborn also provides a very neat example:

[image: Seaborn KDE joyplot]

They call it a joy/ridge plot however: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="white", rc={"axes.facecolor": (0, 0, 0, 0)})

# Create the data
rs = np.random.RandomState(1979)
x = rs.randn(500)
g = np.tile(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"), 50)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, g=g))
m = df.g.map(ord)
df["x"] += m

# Initialize the FacetGrid object
pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(10, rot=-.25, light=.7)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", aspect=15, size=.5, palette=pal)

# Draw the densities in a few steps
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, shade=True, alpha=1, lw=1.5, bw=.2)
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, color="w", lw=2, bw=.2)
g.map(plt.axhline, y=0, lw=2, clip_on=False)

# Define and use a simple function to label the plot in axes coordinates
def label(x, color, label):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .2, label, fontweight="bold", color=color, 
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)

g.map(label, "x")

# Set the subplots to overlap
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25)

# Remove axes details that don't play will with overlap
g.set_titles("")
g.set(yticks=[])
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)
```