# How do I visually stack multiple line graphs above each other in python?

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I was having trouble creating a plot I need which has multiple line graphs.

What I want is a way to graph each of these above the other (say one has a baseline of y=5 I want the next to have a baseline of y=10) and also each of these graphs must block the one above it.

So this will inevitably look like the cover to Joy Divisions Unknown Pleasures here:
           http://cococubed.asu.edu/images/unknown_pleasures/unknown_pleasures.jpg

Except inverted colors and I also would like an answer that utilizes python or numpy or matplotlib.

Comment: Check out this [relevant question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614499/frequency-trail-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Does each plot must be really stacked on top of each other such as curve 1 is y1, curve 2 is y2+y2, curve 3 is y3+y2+y1 ... and so on? Or is just the baseline that must be added?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way. The key point is to use fill_between function and offset each plotted line with some margin (`i*2` in this case). Also, plotting has to start from the top, hence the [::-1] in the arange slice.

```
t=linspace(-2*pi, 2*pi, 1000)
for i in arange(1, pi, 0.01)[::-1]:
    left = exp(-(t + (i - 1) * 2*pi)**2) * cos(t * i)**2 - 1
    right = exp(-(t - (i - 1) * 2*pi)**2) * cos(t * i)**2 - 1 
    vertical_offset = i*2
    fill_between(t, vertical_offset + left + right, facecolor='white')
```

[image]