# How to plot several curves with an offset on the same graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I read a waveform from an oscilloscope. The waveform is divided into 10 segments as a function of time. I want to plot the complete waveform, one segment above (or under) another, 'with a vertical offset', so to speak. Additionally, a color map is necessary to show the signal intensity. I've only been able to get the following plot:

[image]

As you can see, all the curves are superimposed, which is unacceptable. One could add an offset to the y data but this is not how I would like to do it. Surely there is a much neater way of plotting my data? I've tried a few things to solve this issue using pylab but I am not even sure how to proceed and if this is the right way to go.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
import readTrc #helps read binary data from an oscilloscope
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fName = r"...trc"
datX, datY, m = readTrc.readTrc(fName)

segments = m['SUBARRAY_COUNT'] #number of segments

x, y = [], []

for i in range(segments+1):
    x.append(datX[segments*i:segments*(i+1)])
    y.append(datY[segments*i:segments*(i+1)])

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Look through [The Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) and find something similar to what you are trying to do and adapt it for your purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A plot with *a vertical offset* sounds like a [frequency trail](http://www.brendangregg.com/FrequencyTrails/intro.html).
[image: kde_joyplot example from seaborn]

Here's one approach that *does* just adjust the y value.

[Frequency Trail in MatPlotLib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614499/frequency-trail-in-matplotlib)

The same plot has also been coined a joyplot/ridgeline plot. Seaborn has an implementation that creates a series of plots (FacetGrid), and then adjusts the offset between them for a similar effect.

https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_joyplot.html

An example using a line plot might look like:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

segments = 10
points_per_segment = 100

#your data preparation will vary
x = np.tile(np.arange(points_per_segment), segments)
z = np.floor(np.arange(points_per_segment * segments)/points_per_segment)
y = np.sin(x * (1 + z))
        
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z})

pal = sns.color_palette()
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="z", hue="z", aspect=15, height=.5, palette=pal)
g.map(plt.plot, 'x', 'y')
g.map(plt.axhline, y=0, lw=2, clip_on=False)
# Set the subplots to overlap
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.00)
g.set_titles("")
g.set(yticks=[])
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)

plt.show()
```

Out:
[image]

Comment: @DenGor not sure if this helped, would be happy to revise to include more relevant implementation details if it would be helpful, or remove answer entirely if not.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your answer is mostly links. You could either flesh out your answer with code examples or delete the answer and post the links in the comments?

Comment: Thanks DavidG, derived a home-brewed example for further illustration.