# Adjust axes to make space for offset line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot a series of curves in the same Axes each having a constant `y` offset from eachother. Because the data I have needs to be displayed in `log` scale, simply adding a `y` offset to each curve (as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614499/frequency-trail-in-matplotlib)) does not give the desired output.

I have tried using `matplotlib.transforms` to achieve the same, i.e. artificially shifting the curve in `Figure` coordinates. This achieves the desired result, but requires adjusting the `Axes` `y` limits so that the shifted curves are visible. Here is an example to illustrate this, though such data would not require `log` scale to be visible:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

for i in range(1,19):

    x, y = np.arange(200), np.random.rand(200)
    dy = 0.5*i

    shifted = mpl.transforms.offset_copy(ax.transData, y=dy, fig=fig, units='inches')

    ax.set_xlim(0, 200)
    ax.set_ylim(0.1, 1e20)
    ax.set_yscale('log')

    ax.plot(x, y, transform=shifted, c=mpl.cm.plasma(i/18), lw=2)
```

[image]

The problem is that to make all the shifted curves visible, I would need to adjust the `ylim` to a very high number, which compresses all the curves so that the features visible because of the `log` scale cannot be seen anymore.

Since the displayed `y` axis values are meaningless to me, is there any way to artificially extend the `Axes` limits to display all the curves, without having to make the `Figure` very large? Apparently this can be done with [seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46961783/how-to-plot-several-curves-with-an-offset-on-the-same-graph), but if possible I would like to stick to `matplotlib`.

**EDIT**:

This is the kind of data I need to plot (an X-ray diffraction pattern varying with temperature):

[image]

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54729242/4124317) would do the same as in the link, but without seaborn, in case that is what you're asking for.

Comment: That's using separate axes for each plot, I would like to use just one so that I can tailor the offset between curves in order to get some overlap between them (each curve is the same signal as a function of temperature)

Comment: I have added an image to show what I mean.

Comment: You said "Apparently this can be done with seaborn...", so my comment was meant to show how to achieve the same without.

Comment: The [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html) implementation allows for the overlap.

Comment: Yes, due to the line `fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25)` which sets the spacing between axes to a negative value.

Comment: Ahhh I did  not realise that thanks!