# How to make a multiwaveplot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I want to plot a multichannel signal in a way similar to the picture below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lomja.png)

Does someone know if there is a function within matplotlib or any other Python library that makes such plots? I have tried with the joypy library, but the results were not that good.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are simply a couple of line plots offset from each other. You can achieve this using `plt.plot`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614499/frequency-trail-in-matplotlib) might be of interest to you

Comment: [The Matplotlib Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) is always a good place to start and the [Tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html) are instructive.