# how to make rug plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Im making a density plot with matplotlib and I would also like to get rug plot under it. good example to make density plot is here [How to create a density plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150171/how-to-create-a-density-plot-in-matplotlib)

but I couldn't find any good example for rug plot. in R it can be done easly by rug(data).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find an example [here](https://gist.github.com/rgommers/1534517)!

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x1, np.zeros(x1.shape), 'b+', ms=20)  # rug plot
x_eval = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=200)
ax.plot(x_eval, kde1(x_eval), 'k-', label="Scott's Rule")
ax.plot(x_eval, kde1(x_eval), 'r-', label="Silverman's Rule")
```

Seems to be the core of it!

Comment: `np.zeros(x1.shape)` is more direct here as the standard `np.zeros_like(x1)`.

Comment: An even simpler way which will keep the ticks on the bottom axis: `ax.vlines(x1, ymin=0, ymax=0.01)`

Answer (score 15):

You can plot markers at each datapoint.

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sample = np.hstack((np.random.randn(30), np.random.randn(20)+5))
density = stats.kde.gaussian_kde(sample)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))

x = np.arange(-6,12,0.1)
ax.plot(x, density(x))

ax.plot(sample, [0.01]*len(sample), '|', color='k')
```

[image]

Comment: `[0.01]*len(sample)` is probably faster as `np.full_like(sample, 0.01)` (and probably even faster with strides tricks).

Comment: This seems the best pure-mpl answer so far, but how can I make the bottom of the marker ('|') align with the bottom of the axes?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [Seaborn.distplot](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.distplot.html?highlight=distplot), which wraps histogram, KDE and rugs altogether. Figures made by Seaborn are also prettier by default.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sample = np.hstack((np.random.randn(30), np.random.randn(20)+5))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))
sns.distplot(sample, rug=True, hist=False, rug_kws={"color": "g"},
    kde_kws={"color": "k", "lw": 3})
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Note that you can also use the `seaborn.rugplot` function individually if you want more control: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.rugplot.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer for people just looking for a rugplot to use **on a matplotlib axis**:  you can use a seaborn function.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.rugplot(xdata, height=0.025, axis=ax,  color='k')
```

This looks much nicer than a pure-matplotlib kludge because the rug is aligned to (flush with) the x-axis.