# Plot density using observation weights

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikits

Is there a way to plot densities using data that has observation weights?

I have a vector of observations `x` and a vector of integer weights `y`, such that `y1` indicates how many observations we have of `x1`. That is, the density of

```
   x    y 
   1    2
   2    2
   2    3
```

is equal to the density of  `1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2 ,2` (2x1, 5x2). As far as I understand it, 
`matplotlib.pyplot.hist(weights=y)` allow for observation weights when plotting the histogram. Is there any equivalent for computing and plotting the density?

The reason I want the package to be able to do this is that my data is very big, and I'm looking for a more efficient alternative.

Alternatively, I'm open to other packages.

Comment: You only need to generate the densities from the observations?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I want to plot the densities as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150171/how-to-create-a-density-plot-in-matplotlib

Comment: so as I understand it, you only need to create a list that you call a `histogram` and send it to one of the package suggested. Is your trouble creating that list from observations, or do you have a list and you're having trouble with the package? Or both?

Comment: I say that I know functions that allow plotting histograms using observation weights. On the other hand, I'm not aware of functions that allow plotting densities using these weights. I bring the comparison given that densities are somewhat limit cases of histograms. I am not aware of being able to plot densities using histograms.

Comment: Ahhh now I get it...! Sorry, can't help you too much there :)

Comment: see the violin plot in mpl 1.4 and the KDE estimators from scipy.

Answer (score 4):

Statsmodels' kde univariate receives weights in its [fit function](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.kde.KDEUnivariate.fit.html). See the output of the following code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1.,2.],'weight':[2,4]})
weighted = sm.nonparametric.KDEUnivariate(df.x)
noweight = sm.nonparametric.KDEUnivariate(df.x)
weighted.fit(fft=False, weights=df.weight)
noweight.fit()

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
ax1.plot(noweight.support, noweight.density)
ax2.plot(weighted.support, weighted.density)

ax1.set_title('No Weight')
ax2.set_title('Weighted')
```

Output:
[image: No Weight vs Weighted Densities]

Note: Your time concern regarding array creation will probably not be resolved with this. Because as noted in the [source code](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/_modules/statsmodels/nonparametric/kde.html#KDEUnivariate.fit):

> If FFT is False, then a ‘number_of_obs’ x ‘gridsize’ intermediate
>   array is created

Comment: Use `ax1.plot(noweight.support, noweight.density)` to have correct x-axis values. Also, note that the weights need to be a numpy array (or a column in pandas) or you will have the code complaining it can not do `weights.sum()`