# Is there a clean way to generate a line histogram chart?

Tags: python, plot, histogram

I need to create a histogram that plots a line and not a step or bar chart.  I am using python 2.7 The plt.hist function below plots a stepped line and the bins don't line up in the plt.plot function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
noise = np.random.normal(0,1,(1000,1))
(n,x,_) = plt.hist(noise, bins = np.linspace(-3,3,7), histtype=u'step' )  
plt.plot(x[:-1],n)
```

I need the line to correlate with each bin's count at the bin centers as if there was a histtype=u'line' flag to go with the align=u'mid' flag

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: My question would be "why do you want to do this?". What problem are you trying to solve? Looking at the solutions below, this isn't going to give you a true representation of your data. So it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Using scipy, you could [use `stats.gaussian_kde`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) to [estimate the probability density function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4150171/190597):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (1000, ))
density = stats.gaussian_kde(noise)
n, x, _ = plt.hist(noise, bins=np.linspace(-3, 3, 50), 
                   histtype=u'step', density=True)  
plt.plot(x, density(x))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: what unit is the y-axis having here? is it %/100 of occurence or sth. alike?

Comment: @Shushiro: The curves are estimates of a probability distribution. You can think of these curves as having been scaled to ensure the area under their curves is 1.

Comment: Could this be adapted for a histogram where density=False?

Comment: Why do we need the `u` in `u'step'`?

Answer (score 13):

The line plot you are producing does not line up as the x values being used are the bin edges. 
You can calculate the bin centers as follows: `bin_centers = 0.5*(x[1:]+x[:-1])`
Then the complete code would be:

```
noise = np.random.normal(0,1,(1000,1))
n,x,_ = plt.hist(noise, bins = np.linspace(-3,3,7), histtype=u'step' )
bin_centers = 0.5*(x[1:]+x[:-1])
plt.plot(bin_centers,n) ## using bin_centers rather than edges
plt.show()
```

If you want the plot filled to y=0 then use `plt.fill_between(bin_centers,n)`[image: Line histogram at bin centers]

Comment: The area under the orange curve per bin is wrong, especially much too low for the two central bins.

Answer (score 9):

[Matplotlib's thumbnail gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) is usually quite helpful in situations like yours. A combination of [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_features.html) and [this one](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_cumulative.html) from the gallery with some customizations is probably very close to what you have in mind:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu = 0
sigma = 1
noise = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size=1000)
num_bins = 7
n, bins, _ = plt.hist(noise, num_bins, normed=1, histtype='step')
y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu, sigma)
plt.plot(bins, y, 'r--')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Also, increasing the number of bins helps...

[image]

Comment: it was found that matplotlib.mlab removed the normpdf() function

Comment: Replace `normed=1` by `density=True` and `mlab.normpdf` by `from scipy.stats import norm` `y = norm.pdf(bins, mu, sigma)`