# how to make a line trend chart from the given data

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, linechart

I have a histogram which is being generated from one of the dataframe column. But I want to make line similar to histogram.

I tried to extract histogram data & plot a line chart but didn't worked.

```
data = [
    202.91,
    236.04,
    306.28,
    ...
    315.83,
    190.03
]

plt.hist(data)
plt.show()
```

This code generate a histogram, but I need a line chart which shows the trend

Comment: What do you mean by "line similar to histogram"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a clean way to generate a line histogram chart in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872723/is-there-a-clean-way-to-generate-a-line-histogram-chart-in-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872723/is-there-a-clean-way-to-generate-a-line-histogram-chart-in-python

Comment: title should be changed to 'how to make a line trend chart'

Comment: @DaveR do you have solution in your mind for it.?

Comment: @ragrwl gave the right answer. If this is what you wanted, the title should be 'how to make a line trend chart overlaying an histogram' or something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows the step histogram line and a line plot on it passing from the center of each bin.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.randn(1000)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, histtype=u'step')
plt.plot(bins[:-1]+(bins[1]-bins[0])/2, n)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: for this solution, how can i just get line not histogram.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `histtype = 'step'` option. This would be the easiest. In your specific example,

```
plt.hist(data, histtype='step')
plt.show()
```

Comment: didn't suits my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are extracting data from a dataframe you could use `pandas` only as in the following example

```py
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"data":np.random.randn(1000)})

ax = df["data"].plot.kde();
df['data'].hist(rwidth=0.8, density=True,ax=ax);
```

[image]