# Python/Scipy kde fit, scaling

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, histogram, kernel-density

I have a Series in Python and I'd like to fit a density to its histogram. Question: is there a slick way to use the values from np.histogram() to achieve this result? **(see Update below)**

My current problem is that the kde fit I perform has (seemingly) unwanted kinks, as depicted in the second plot below. I was hoping for a kde fit that is monotone decreasing based on a histogram, which is the first figure depicted. Below I've included my current code. Thanks in advance

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde as kde

df[var].hist()
plt.show()  # shows the original histogram
density = kde(df[var])
xs = np.arange(0, df[var].max(), 0.1)
ys = density(xs)
plt.plot(xs, ys)  # a pdf with kinks
```

Alternatively, is there a slick way to use

```
count, div = np.histogram(df[var])
```

and then scale the count array to apply kde() to it?

[image: original historgram]

[image: kde_fit]

### Update

Based on cel's comment below (should've been obvious, but I missed it!), I was implicitly under-binning in this case using the default params in pandas.DataFrame.hist(). In the updated plot I used

```
df[var].hist(bins=100)
```

I'll leave this post up in case others find it useful but won't mind if it gets taken down as 'too localized' etc.

[image]

Comment: It's a bad idea to use a histogram with very few bins to approximate the density. Try using more bins and you will probably see that your density looks more like the KDE estimate...

Comment: thank you, feel free to post as answer if you'd like me to 'formally' accept

Comment: This was just a minor issue. I think it's a good way to understand the benefits and limitations of the histogram approach, though: the number of bins is critical and a too low/too high number of bins can give a distorted view on the data. Heads up, now comes the funny part of data analysis: Understanding what process could have created such a fancy distribution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was under-binning as mentioned by cel, see comments above. It was clarifying to set bins=100 in pd.DataFrame.histo() *which defaults to bins=10*.

See also:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Number_of_bins_and_width

Answer (score 2):

If you increase the bandwidth using the `bw_method` parameter, then the kde will look smoother. This example comes from [Justin Peel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4152016/190597); the code has been modified to take advantage of the `bw_method`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

data = [1.5]*7 + [2.5]*2 + [3.5]*8 + [4.5]*3 + [5.5]*1 + [6.5]*8
density1 = gaussian_kde(data)
bandwidth = 1.5
density2 = gaussian_kde(data, bw_method=bandwidth)
xs = np.linspace(0,8,200)
plt.plot(xs,density1(xs), label='bw_method=None')
plt.plot(xs,density2(xs), label='bw_method={}'.format(bandwidth))
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: In my opinion in this case increasing the bandwidth is a very bad suggestion. See how many counts are in the peak. This is clearly not caused by random noise... Increasing the bandwidth is to some extend similar to displaying the data with a histogram with a very low amount of bins. You are basically cheating :)

Comment: thank you, though in my specific case: smoothing on an under-binned sample would've further hidden my basic problem. see cel's comment above and my update. i'll certainly keep bandwidth in mind for future tasks

Comment: @cel: I take it you disapprove of [spherical cows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow) :)