# how to group pandas timestamps plot several plots in one figure and stack them together in matplotlib?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, machine-learning, data-visualization, data-analysis

I have a data frame with perfectly organised timestamps, like below:

[image]

It's a web log, and the timestamps go though the whole year. I want to ***cut them into each day and show the visits within each hour and plot them into the same figure and stack them all together.*** Just like the pic shown below:

[image]

I am doing well on cutting them into days and plot the visits of a day individually, but I am having trouble plotting them and stacking them together. The primary tool I am using is ***Pandas and Matplotlib***.

Any advices and suggestions? Much Appreciated!

---

**Edited:**

My Code is as below:

The timestamps are: https://gist.github.com/adamleo/04e4147cc6614820466f7bc05e088ac5

And the dataframe looks like this:
[image]

I plotted the timestamp density through the whole period used the code below:

```
timestamps_series_all = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.Series(unique_visitors_df.time_stamp))
timestamps_series_all_toBePlotted = pd.Series(1, index=timestamps_series_all)
timestamps_series_all_toBePlotted.resample('D').sum().plot()
```

and got the result:

[image]

I plotted timestamps within one day using the code:

```
timestamps_series_oneDay = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.Series(unique_visitors_df.time_stamp.loc[unique_visitors_df["date"] == "2014-08-01"]))
timestamps_series_oneDay_toBePlotted = pd.Series(1, index=timestamps_series_oneDay)
timestamps_series_oneDay_toBePlotted.resample('H').sum().plot()
```

and the result:
[image]

And now I am stuck.

I'd really appreciate all of your help!

Comment: Have you considered sharing some of your code?

Comment: @StephenRauch Hey buddy, I just updated the post. have a look please. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
#https://gist.github.com/adamleo/04e4147cc6614820466f7bc05e088ac5 to L
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':L})
print (df.head())
                  date
0  2014-08-01 00:05:46
1  2014-08-01 00:14:47
2  2014-08-01 00:16:05
3  2014-08-01 00:20:46
4  2014-08-01 00:23:22

#convert to datetime if necessary
df['date']  = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] )
#resample by Hours, get count and create df
df = df.resample('H', on='date').size().to_frame('count')
#extract date and hour
df['days'] = df.index.date
df['hours'] = df.index.hour
#pivot and plot
#maybe check parameter kind='density' from http://stackoverflow.com/a/33474410/2901002
#df.pivot(index='days', columns='hours', values='count').plot(rot='90')
#edit: last line change to below:
df.pivot(index='hours', columns='days', values='count').plot(rot='90')
```

Comment: Thank you so much buddy, this answer really helped. However the last line was a bit twisted, so I changed to `df.pivot(index='hours', columns='days', values='count').plot(rot='90')` and it worked perfectly. Appreciated!