# pandas graph not appearing on screen

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone help me find out why is this code not displaying any type of graph in my screen?

```
import pandas as pd
data = [1.5]*7 + [2.5]*2 + [3.5]*8 + [4.5]*3 + [5.5]*1 + [6.5]*8
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.plot(kind='density')
```

This example was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150171/how-to-create-a-density-plot-in-matplotlib). The code is being run via terminal on Ubuntu

Comment: what happens when you run the code?

Comment: @lev Sorry, Nathan answered it bellow. I forgot marking it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to do this too, though I don't have the proper OS to check for you:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# your other code here
plt.show() # at the end
```

Comment: Isn't this wrong? Using another library method to display -- It worked