# How to plot probability density function of circular statistics around a circle in python?

Tags: python

I need to plot the pdf curve of circular statistic data around a circle in python. I konw how it does in R language, but I could not find the python example for it in the web.
I only found the example of circular histogram as [enter link description here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_bar_demo.html)

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `polar` plot in `matplotlib`. Here is an example:
https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/gallery/misc/transoffset.html#sphx-glr-gallery-misc-transoffset-py

If you want to plot the list `y`, here are the steps.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

# create equispaced angles (in radians)
xs = [i / len(y) * 2 *math.pi  for i in range(len(y))]
# to make a good circle, duplicate the first entry
xs.append(0)
y.append(y[0])
# plot
plt.polar(xs, y)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But could you please give the complete code so that i can run and see? By the way, I want to plot a pdf curve like vonmises curve over a circle, not descrete points.

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150171/how-to-create-a-density-plot-in-matplotlib to generate the density function. Plot it as above.