# Add density curve on the histogram

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I am able to make histogram in python but I am unable to add density curve , I see many code which are using different ways to add density curve on histogram but I am not sure how to get on my code

**I have added density = true but not able to get density curve on histogram**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
X=df['A']

hist, bins = np.histogram(X, bins=10,density=True)
width = 0.7 * (bins[1] - bins[0])
center = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2
plt.bar(center, hist, align='center', width=width)
plt.show()
```

Comment: [Take a look at this answer using seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32803224/3595907)

Comment: You'll need seaborn's `distplot()` or `histplot()`. The function names and parameters changed a bit in the latest version (0.11).  Note that `np.histogram(..., density=True)` means that the histogram will be normalized such that the total area sums to 1, so it can share the y-axis with a kdeplot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`distplot` has been removed: [removed in a future version of seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html). Therefore, alternatives are to use [`histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot) and [`displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot).

#### `sns.histplot`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
X = df['A']

sns.histplot(X, kde=True, bins=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### `sns.displot`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
X = df['A']

sns.displot(X, kde=True, bins=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

### `distplot` has been removed

Here is an approach using [`distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) method of `seaborn`. Also, mentioned  in the comments:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
X = df['A']

sns.distplot(X, kde=True, bins=20, hist=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Pandas also has `kde` plot:

```
hist, bins = np.histogram(X, bins=10,density=True)
width = 0.7 * (bins[1] - bins[0])
center = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2
plt.bar(center, hist, align='center', width=width, zorder=1)

# density plot
df['A'].plot.kde(zorder=2, color='C1')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]