# How do I get a smooth outline (with filled area) for this plot?

Tags: python, probability-density, best-fit-curve

PDF from histogram data
[image: PDF from histogram data]

I am trying to get a PDF with a smoother outline. Also, the area under the curve must be filled. How can I get the curve of best fit for this?

This is the code I have used.

```py
plt.hist(
    data,
    range=[0, 60],
    bins=60,
    density=True,
    label="In bulk",
    histtype="stepfilled",
    alpha=0.5,
)
```

Comment: Think you want to plot a kernel density estimate rather than a histogram.  Check out the seaborn package for an easy version, or you need to use scipy to estimate it then plot manually.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4150171/1358308

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a density plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150171/how-to-create-a-density-plot-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

Your description is vague, but as far as I understood you want to fill everything under the line each bar is spanning!

You can use `.fill_between` for that! Refer to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html).